# how to pass unknown numbers lists value into input field

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have developed a web app using flask, jinja template and bootstrap. It has a function called save in which I have passed the value of a paragraph and it saves it in .txt file. But I want to save a list of items in the .txt file. So I want to know how to put the unknown numbers of lists values into the input fields. If there is any solution to it tell me. It will be very helpful. Thanks in advance. The codes are given below.

Code of save function:

```
import os.path
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@app.route('/save',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def save():
    #save_path = 'C:/'
    raw_text = request.form['save_text']
    file_name = 'yoursummary' + timestr + '.txt'
    completeName = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Documents', file_name)
    with open(completeName, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(raw_text)
    return '<h1 align="center" style="padding: 20px;">Summary is saved in Documents!</h1>'
```

Code of paragraph portion:

```
<p style="color: white;font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 400;padding-left: 30px;">{{ final_summary }}</p>
<form method="POST" action="/save">
<input type="hidden" id="save_text" name="save_text" value="{{ final_summary }}">
<button class="btn transparent_btn_blue" type="submit" style="margin-top: 30px;font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 700;">Save</button>
</form>
```

Code of list portion:

```
<p style="color: white;font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 400;padding-left: 30px;">Number of {{choice}}s: <span style="color:red;">{{num_of_results}} </span></p>
<ul>{% for i in results %}
  <li style="color: white;font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 400;padding-left: 30px;">{{i}}</li>
{%endfor %}
</ul>
<form method="POST" action="/save">
   <input type="hidden" id="save_text" name="save_text" value="">
   <button class="btn transparent_btn_blue" type="submit" style="margin-top: 30px;font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 700;">Save</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: You should generate dynamic input fields on the client side and have code that will collect it for posting to the server.

Comment: @balderman how to do it?